# How to run docker-compose in ECS? (not manually from my windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I've been looking for long time on how to run a `docker-compose` file on ECS, but all I find is:

- `aws ecs` command line: I would prefer to be somehow in the task definition I already setup for my container. Also I can't understand what will happen to my cluster and task definition if I run this command. Will just delete my task definition and create a new one? create a new task with this docker compose and I need to delete my existing task? Super confusing
- `docker ecs` : again, same problem

Is there any way to upload the docker compose with the GUI or `aws sdk` for node?